# SMTP server terminates connection before sending QUIT command

Tags: c#, smtp, tcplistener

We have written a simple (standard .net tcp async logic) SMTP listener which listens on 25 port for incoming connections from other SMTP servers.

It process all mandatory commands like FROM, RCPT TO, etc.

With some servers it works well but, some SMTP servers (like Microsoft outlook) terminates connection before sending QUIT command and then re-send the same mails again and again.

Anything we have missed?

Comment: What are you trying to archive in the end? To build your own SMTP? It seems that outlook have a low wait time for 250 queued mail for delivery, and then kills the session instead.

Comment: @farnholdt
Yes, it is small SMTP server, that just analize incoming emails and marks them as recieved and generates a report. Microsoft SMTP OUTLOOK server sends only one email (there are no mor emails in queue) and drops connection right after DATA recieved \r\n.\r\n and sometimes right after we responded with 250 OK

Comment: If you don't want to keep develope your own, you can take a look at http://www.wrapstogo.net, that is a smtp c# library. It can handle this situation with MS. If you wanna go on, it is a matter of making your code faster, so the response is right after they complete sending data.

Comment: @farnholdt thank you for the answer, but our code is fast enough and this is actually is not a problem. We are still testing one more solution that does not relate to performance or anything simmilar. I will let know when we get a result for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
354 Start mail input; end with<CR><LF>.<CR><LF>

we had to send <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you had to send <CR><LF>.<CR><LF> after your recevied <CR><LF>.<CR><LF> from server?

Comment: @DmytroI. yes! :) hmm, I do not remember exactly, maybe <cr><lf>.<cr><lf> instead of \r\n.\r\n